# Time complexity of level order traversal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity, tree-traversal

What is the time complexity of binary tree level order traversal ? Is it O(n) or O(log n)?

```
void levelorder(Node *n)
{    queue < Node * >q;
     q.enqueue(n);

     while(!q.empty())
      {
         Node * node = q.front();
         DoSmthwith node;
         q.dequeue();          
         if(node->left != NULL)
         q.enqueue(node->left);
         if (node->right != NULL)
         q.enqueue(node->right);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `O(n)`, or to be exact `Theta(n)`.

Have a look on each node in the tree - each node is "visited" at most 3 times, and at least once) - when it is discovered (all nodes), when coming back from the left son (non leaf) and when coming back from the right son (non leaf), so total of 3*n visits at most and n visites at least per node. Each visit is `O(1)` (queue push/pop), totaling in  - `Theta(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to approach this problem is identifying that a level-order traversal is very similar to the [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) of a graph. A breadth-first traversal has a time complexity that is `O(|V| + |E|)` where `|V|` is the number of vertices and `|E|` is the number of edges.

In a tree, the number of edges is around equal to the number of vertices. This makes it overall **linear** in the number of nodes.

In particular, since each node in the tree (with the exception of the root node) has one incoming edge (from its one parent node), we get, `|E| = |V| - 1`.

Therefore, `O(|V| + |E|) = O(|V| + |V| - 1) = O(|V|)`.

Answer (score 0):

The time and space complexities are O(n). n = no. of nodes.

> Space complexity - Queue size would be proportional to number of nodes
>   O(n)
>
> Time complexity - O(n) as each node is visited twice. Once during
>   enqueue operation and once during dequeue operation.

This is a special case of BFS. You can read about BFS (Breadth First Search) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search .